# CSS Position Absolute Make Behind Element Cannot be Use

Tags: html, css

i have a problem like this.

```css
#relative{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  text-align:center;
}
button{
  margin:10px auto;
  width:200px;
  height:auto;
  border:1px solid;
  border-radius:5px;
}
#absolute{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    height: 250px;
    width: 100%;
    border: solid 1px #000000;
    color: blue;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 60px;
    /*opacity:0;*/
}
button:hover{
  background-color:#eed5a4;
}
```

```html
<div id="relative">
<button>
Hover me if you can.
</button>
<div id="absolute">
Absolute its me dude!!<br>
If me >> opacity:0<br>
Button still cant be hover.
</div>
</div>
```

Any solution for this, and i dont know to use the good english language
Note : button keep like this, do not change the position absolute too.
- my english so bad :(

Comment: Also: read into `pointer-events: none`. Should work if added on the parent as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `position:relative;` and a higher `z-index` than that of the **#absolute** div to the button itself, like so:

**HTML**

```
<button id="relative-button">Hover me if you can.</button>
```

**CSS**

```
#absolute { z-index:1 }

#relative-button { position:relative; z-index:2 }
```

Comment: What the hell man, its awsome :D. i really happy now.
Thanks dude.

Comment: Done dude :) :D

Comment: it was a nice idea

Comment: @jishnu V S arait

Answer (score 1):

replace button css like this

```
button {
   border: 1px solid;
   border-radius: 5px;
   height: auto;
   margin: 10px auto;
   position: relative; /* newly added */
   width: 200px;
   z-index: 9; /* newly added */
}
```

Comment: its nor for all , i just want to realize him what happens, just add class and add `z-index` to them , and your answer were right and i am not the downvoter

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @daniel lisik, you are awesome people. Extraordinary

```css
#relative{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  text-align:center;
}
button{
  position:relative;
  z-index:5;
  margin:10px auto;
  width:200px;
  height:auto;
  border:1px solid;
  border-radius:5px;
}
#absolute{
    position: absolute;
    z-index:1;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    height: 250px;
    width: 100%;
    border: solid 1px #000000;
    color: blue;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 60px;
    /*opacity:0;*/
}
button:hover{
  background-color:#eed5a4;
}
```

```html
<div id="relative">
<button>
Hover me if you can.
</button>
<div id="absolute">
Absolute its me dude!!<br>
If me >> opacity:0<br>
Button still cant be hover.
</div>
</div>
```